# Rails Routes Collision Handling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, seo

I have an interesting routing situation that I'm having some trouble handling...  This is for a rails 2.3 app, here's the scenario:

```
route a:
/:trans_type/:country_code/:property_types

route b:
/:trans_type/:country_code/:location
```

These two routes share the same location in the route so there needs to be a :requirement set on either :location or :property_types to differentiate the two.

Since :location is pretty wide open, :property_types is the way to go because I have a module that can easily compile a list of of all existing property types to do a regex match against.

The problem:
/for-sale/us/apartment-loft

Since :property_types is an array, I have to parse multiple property_types out of the params object (outside of the router, obviously).  If I have a case like this, it's not possible for me to do a regex match in the router against a known property type because :property_types can potentially return several hyphenated types.

**My question then is, Is it possible for me to take the :property_types string and modify it specifically for the :requirements matching?  If I can replace 'apartment-loft' to just be 'apartment' for that match (/^\w+/), then I have something I can realistically regex match against.**

```
Here's what the two routes actually look like:

map.location ":transaction/:country_code/:property_types",
  :controller => "search",
  :action => "location",
  :requirements => { :transaction => /(for-sale|for-rent|auction|new_development)/, :country_code => /\w\w/, :property_types => /(#{prop_types})/ }

map.location ":transaction/:country_code/:location",
  :controller => "search",
  :action => "location",
  :requirements => { :transaction => /(for-sale|for-rent|auction|new_development)/, :country_code => /\w\w/}
```

The above implementation works fine for routes that have one property_type, but for routes that have multiple hyphenated property_types, I'm hitting a wall.

Answer (score 1):

If it's feasible, I would suggest creating explicit routes and controller actions for these two cases:

```
map.location ":transaction/:country_code/property-types/:property_types",
  :controller => "search",
  :action => "by_property_type",
  :requirements => { :transaction => /(for-sale|for-rent|auction|new_development)/, :country_code => /\w\w/, :property_types => /(#{prop_types})/ }

map.location ":transaction/:country_code/:location",
  :controller => "search",
  :action => "by_location",
  :requirements => { :transaction => /(for-sale|for-rent|auction|new_development)/, :country_code => /\w\w/}
```

Then you don't have to worry so much about regex matching at the router and you can do it in the controller instead.

Comment: You make a good point... Maybe if I use route globbing I can achieve a similar result...  /for-sale/us/apartment/loft/new-development.  This will require me make some big internal changes and would not conform with the seo rules I have to follow, but those could possibly be changed.  With this approach I can do explicit matches against the types and not worry about colliding with a possible location search.